# Rspec: expect(request).to not_redirect? (opposite of redirect_to)

Tags: redirect, rspec, negate

I've got a request test in rspec that tests for several potential redirects from an endpoint, such as:

```
get registrations_path
expect(response).to redirect_to(new_registration_path)
```

In one case, I expect it to not redirect. Is there a way to negate the matcher `redirect_to` ? Or a matcher that explicitly asserts `not_redirect`?

I've tried variations such as these, without success:

```
expect(response).not_to redirect_to(nil)
expect(response).not_to redirect
expect(response).to not_redirect
```

I do have other tests that test for specifics of a non-redirecting response...but I want this high-level test to flesh out a suite of redirect tests.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite as tight as `.to not_redirect`, but is at least concise and obvious to understand:

```
it { expect(response).not_to have_http_status(:redirect) }
```

When the test fails, it gives a useful response:

```
 1. Failure/Error: expect(response).not_to have_http_status(:redirect)
        expected the response not to have a redirect status code (3xx) but it was 302
```